# How can I organize multiple main files in one project in C?

Tags: c, netbeans, projects-and-solutions

I am currently going through the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives) problems, and I am using the Netbeans IDE.

However, I am being forced to create a new project for every problem I try to solve, because I'm only allowed **one main file** per project.

It's becoming quite a pain, and I would like to have multiple `main.c` files in the same project. How can I achieve this without any problems when I try to compile?

Something like this would be good:

```
Project Euler Problems
|
----- problem_1.c
|
----- problem_2.c
|
.
.
.
```

Any ideas?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Maybe solve each problem in its own file as a function, and then call needed function from main file?

Comment: Sonds like an XY-problem. Using a seperate project-directory for each **project** is a commonly accepted practice for good reasons. So the question is actually what the pain is in creating a new project. That also depends on your toolchain (IDE, etc.).

Comment: @Olaf : It's not exactly a pain, I just thought it's not really common to do something like this.

Comment: why one project each time? is there another way of forming a problem other than hard coding it in the main function?

Comment: Project Euler problems are very small, so it is easier to just write my code directly in a main function. Sometimes I write extra functions, but I try to keep everything in one file.

Comment: So why use an IDE at all? Like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: What do you suggest I use? A text editor like SublimeText?

Comment: I use a common directory and project with a set of files, but only one of the files has the name that is compiled by the project. I then rename the files to switch between which one will get compiled.

Answer (score 1):

In C language, main function is the entry point where control enter the program, so you can have exactly one main function in one project, thus it is impossible to have multiple `main.c` files in one project.

As the first comment suggested, you can

> solve each problem in its own file as a function and call it in your
>   only `main.c` file.